# Transfer Data from Click Handler to Content of ASP.NET Web Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

Sometimes you're too much of a noob to know where to start to look up the answer...

I have an ASP.NET page that uses a click handler. Long story short, I end up with an array in the event handler.

I want to get that array to a table for displaying certain elements of the array. I don't see an obvious way to do that. The event handler doesn't return any data.

I suspect I'm supposed to make a view class and bind it to a data grid.

Comment: is this a standard webforms type of project with the this click handler being in the code behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need a view class.

You can add a DataGrid or GridView in your presentation layer, for example MyGrid, then in your event handler do something like:
MyGrid.DataSource = MyArray;
MyGrid.DataBind();

Another option is to put a literal into your GUI with and mark it runat=server so that you can access it in your code .

Then in your event handler you can loop through the array and write an html table to a string or using stringbuilder, and display that in the literal.

Comment: I ended up creating a view class, using it in a generic list, and configuring the grid datasource to use it, as you suggested. +1 for the literal trick :)